# Pdf files editing and saving in browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, web-applications

The scenario is that I have several editable pdfs that need to be displayed edited and saved all in a web based application.

I know this question has been asked before but I'd like to review the options. I work as a junior developer and I am being asked to research this. I don't think its possible as the pdfs are opened and viewed in different browser plugins that my code doesn't have access to but I still would like to know for sure before I report back to my superior. Is there any way I can tap into some API that allows for editing and saving on a webpage?

Comment: Those to libraries might work for you
https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib
https://github.com/DevelopingMagic/pdfassembler

Answer (score 0):

you could try this :-
 A general-purpose, web standards-based platform for parsing and rendering PDFs
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/